# Передача аргумента с функции в другую функцию через цикл

Tags: python, циклы

Имееться следующий код:

```
def total_inc_dec(x):
  cnt = 0
  for i in range(10**x):
      if i in range(0,100):
          cnt += 1
      elif addf(i):
          cnt += 1
  return cnt

def addf(x):
    le = len(str(x))
    cn = 0
    cn1 = 0
    for j in range(le-1):
        if str(x)[j] >= str(x)[j + 1]:
            cn += 1
        elif str(x)[j] <= str(x)[j + 1]:
            cn1 += 1
    if cn or cn1 == le-1:
        return True

print(total_inc_dec(3))
```

Надо чтобы когда addf возвращает True, cnt увеличивалось на единицу, а выскакивает ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "----------", line 295, in <module>
print(total_inc_dec(3))
  File "----------", line 279, in total_inc_dec
    elif addf(i):
  File "----------", line 288, in addf
    if x[j] >= x[j + 1]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Еще когда я передаю аргумент в функцию addf в виде числа из цикла то получаю
Type 'int' doesn't have expected attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: У меня ваш код исполняется нормально.

Comment: Судя по ошибке вы изменения в редакторе не сохранили или ещё что-то в этом роде, у вас без `str` этот код исполняется: `if x[j] >= x[j + 1]:`